# Duplicate results in MYSQL Query involving three tables

Tags: mysql

The following MySQL query is supposed to list associated showing date, time, and the capacity of the theatre that the movie 'Batman' would be showing in.

```
select distinct s.Date "Showing Date", s.Time "Showing Time", t.Capacity "capacity" 
from CustomerShowing cs, Showing s, Movie m, Theatre t 
where cs.SID = s.SID and s.MID = m.MID and s.RN = t.RN and m.Name = 'Batman';
```

The results look like:

```
02-11-2016  12:35:00    17     
02-11-2016  09:30:00    5    
02-11-2016  09:30:00    5 //the second result repeated..    
02-11-2016  09:30:00    5 //and repeated again..    
02-11-2016  09:30:00    5 //etc..    
02-11-2016  09:30:00    5
```

when they should be

```
02-11-2016  12:35:00 17
02-11-2016  09:30:00 5
```

Edit: Note that the query is fine when using distinct, I mean't without using distinct (!!!)

Comment: You can use group by. Check following query.

Comment: A result set without a data set is like a stick without a lollipop. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are doing a cross join over all the tables thus you are getting duplicates. Use inner joins

```
select distinct s.Date "Showing Date", s.Time "Showing Time",     t.Capacity "capacity" 
from CustomerShowing cs
join Showing s on cs.SID = s.ID
join Movie m on s.MID = m.MID
join Theatre t on s.RN = t.RN
where m.Name = 'Batman';
```

Comment: I still get the same results, I just realized I posted a version of my query using distinct, so obviously the results will properly have two rows. I don't think this will be consistent with different data sets though. I can't really change the question now, but the original query in my post has the same results as the one you posted. When distinct is taken away is when the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. Here used one to one relationship.

```
select distinct s.Date as 'Showing Date', s.Time as 'Showing Time', t.Capacity 
as 'capacity' from CustomerShowing cs INNER JOIN Showing s ON cs.SID = s.SID 
INNER JOIN Movie m ON  s.MID = m.MID INNER JOIN Theatre t ON s.RN = t.RN WHERE 
m.Name = 'Batman';
```

Unless

```
select s.Date "Showing Date", s.Time "Showing Time", t.Capacity "capacity" 
from CustomerShowing cs, Showing s, Movie m, Theatre t 
where cs.SID = s.SID and s.MID = m.MID and s.RN = t.RN and m.Name = 'Batman'
group by s.Date,s.Time,t.Capacity
```

Comment: This will work without distinct. Because here used one to one relationship.